# How to make JS/Jquery Css and HTML popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I am trying to make a html,css and JS/jquery popup. I want it to be a button that when it gets clicked, shows a div tag that also can also be closed. If someone could post answer ASAP that would be extremely helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what have you tried, show some code. We only help with problems with your code we don't create it for you.

Comment: Simplest way: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: Jeffman you're code was what I was looking for but labels and buttons sadly do not work. Do you know a way to make a popup with labels and buttons with same concept as that one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the style provided should style the window to look like facebooks style. I just copied it from a project i'm working on.

The html is also copied, bascially click on the link and it will show the div in a jquery dialog box.

Remember to link to the jquery files, which I haven't included.

I hope this helps.

/* 
        Document   : fbdialog
        Created on : Jul 29, 2013, 7:33:42 PM
        Author     : danny
        Description:
            Purpose of the stylesheet follows.
    */

```
/* Facebook Dialogue Styles */
.ui-widget-overlay {
background:url(images/overlay.png) repeat 0 0;
}

.ui-dialog {
background:rgba(82,82,82,0.7);
border-radius:8px;
-webkit-border-radius:8px;
padding:10px;
}

.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar {
background:#6D84B4;
border:1px solid #3B5998;
font-family:"lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
color:#FFF;
font-size:14px;
font-weight:700;
padding:5px;
}

.fb-dialogue {
border-left:1px solid #555;
border-right:1px solid #555;
border-bottom:1px solid #CCC;
background-color:#FFF;
overflow:hidden;
display:none;
padding:0;
}

.fb-dialogue p,.fb-dialogue div {
font-family:"lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
font-size:13px;
}

.ui-widget-content {
padding-top: 15px;
background:none none 50% top repeat-x;

}

.ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
display:none;
}

.ui-dialog .ui-corner-all {
-moz-border-radius:0;
-webkit-border-radius:0;
border-radius:0;
}

.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane {
background:#F2F2F2;
border-left:1px solid #555;
border-right:1px solid #555;
border-bottom:1px solid #555;
margin:0;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 40px;
padding-right: 15px;
}

.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane button {
margin:0px;
padding:4px 12px;
float: right;
}

.ui-state-default,.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default {
color:#FFF;
background:#6D84B4;
border-color:#29447E;
}

.ui-state-hover,.ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover {
background:#6D84B4;
border-color:#29447E;
}

.ui-state-active,.ui-widget-content .ui-state-active {
background:#4F6AA3;
border-bottom-color:#29447E;
box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.05);
-webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}

.ui-button-text-only .ui-button-text {
padding:2;
}



</style>



<a class="open-event" id="pbutton" href="javascript:void(null);" onclick="showDetailsDialog();">Click Here</a>

<div id="confirmDialog" class="fb-dialogue" >
                    <p>
                        Here is the text of your div window!
                    </p>
                    </br>
                </div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
               function showDetailsDialog() {
                    $("#confirmDialog").dialog({
                        title: "Signup Confirmation",
                        resizable: true,
                        width: 400,
                        position: ['50%',300],
                        draggable: true,
                        buttons: {
                            "Confirm": function () {
                                $('#confirmDialog').dialog('close');   
                             },
                        }

                    });
                });
            </script>

    <div id="confirmDialog" class="fb-dialogue" >
                <p>
                    Here is the text of your div window!
                </p>
                </br>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If by popup you mean tooltip, there are several plugins for the JqueryUI framework totoltip I've used such as this one.

http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/any-html.html

If you are looking for more of a popup window, just create a separate page and use Javascript window.open.

Comment: No not a tooltip, but also not a window. I mean for example a div tag that does not show until you click on something and disapears when you click something else

Answer (score 0):

I use [JQuery Confirm](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/#ajaxloading)
Check the documentation [here](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/#ajaxloading).
It's easy to implement.
You will need Bootstrap, Jquery and confirm-JS.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Demo of jquery.confirm with Bootstrap 3</title>
    <!--bootstrap-->
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--JQuery-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <!--confirm-js-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.0.3/jquery-confirm.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.0.3/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>Demo</h1>
        </div>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="col-lg-3"></th>
                    <th class="col-lg-1">Demo</th>
                    <th class="col-lg-8">Code</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Confirmation dialog customized with JS:</td>
                    <td><button class="btn btn-primary" id="complexConfirm">Click me</button></td>
                    <td>
                        <pre>&lt;button class="btn btn-primary" id="complexConfirm"&gt;Click me&lt;/button&gt;</pre>
                        <pre class="prettyprint"><code>$("#complexConfirm").confirm({
                        title:"Delete confirmation",
                        text:"This is very dangerous, you shouldn't do it! Are you really really sure?",
                        confirm: function(button) {
                            alert("You just confirmed.");
                        },
                        cancel: function(button) {
                            alert("You aborted the operation.");
                        },
                        confirmButton: "Yes I am",
                        cancelButton: "No"
                    });</code></pre>
                    </td>
                </tr>
               
            </tbody>
        </table>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#complexConfirm").confirm({
    title: 'Confirm!',
    content: 'Simple confirm!',
    theme: 'supervan', // 'material', 'bootstrap'
    backgroundDismiss: false,
    backgroundDismissAnimation: 'glow',
    buttons: {
        confirm: function () {
            $.alert('Confirmed!');
        },
        cancel: function () {
            $.alert('Canceled!');
        },
        somethingElse: {
            text: 'Something else',
            btnClass: 'btn-primary',
            keys: ['enter', 'shift'],
            action: function(){
                $.alert('Something else?');
            }
        }
    }
  });
</script>
    </div>
    <!--bootstrap-->
    <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```